# Copy List items using REST/JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, json

I'm very new to REST and JSON, I want to copy list items from one list to another list in the same site on button click, both the lists are of same type but with different column names and they are 'Tasks' lists. I have the code to get the list items from a list and its below,

```
// Getting list items based on ODATA Query
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {

    // Executing our items via an ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });

}
```

I have the code to create an item in the list and its as below,

```
    function createListItem(webUrl,listName, itemProperties, success, failure) 
{    
 $.ajax(
{       
 url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,   
     type: "POST",   
     processData: false,  
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: 
{   
         "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }, 
       success: function (data) 
{           
 success(data.d);   
     },      
  error: function (data)
 {            
failure(data.responseJSON.error);    
    }  
  });
} 
 //Usage: create taskvar taskProperties = 
{   
 'TaskName': 'Order Approval',    'AssignedToId': 12};
 createListItem('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project/','Tasks',taskProperties,function(task){ 
   console.log('Task' + task.TaskName + ' has been created');  
 }, 
 function(error){ 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
 });
```

Now how to pass the required feild values from `getListItems funtion` to `createListItem function`, and how to make all these work on button click?

Comment: can you provide the complete code. I see that complete and failure method are not discussed in the sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### How to copy List Item using SharePoint 2013 REST

```
function getListItem(webUrl, listName,listItemId, complete, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}



function createListItem(webUrl,listName, itemProperties, complete, failure) 
{    
    $.ajax({       
       url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",   
       type: "POST",   
       processData: false,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
       headers: {   
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
       }, 
       success: function (data) {           
           complete(data.d);   
       },      
       error: function (data) {            
           failure(data.responseJSON.error);    
       }  
    });
} 



function copyListItem(webUrl,sourceListName,targetListName,listItemId,complete,failure)
{
    getListItem(webUrl,sourceListName,listItemId,
    function(sourceItem){
        //prepare item
        var copyItem = {};
        for (var propertyName in sourceItem) {
          if (sourceItem.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
              if(sourceItem[propertyName] != null && sourceItem[propertyName].hasOwnProperty('__deferred'))  //exclude deffered objects 
              {
                  continue;
              }
              if(propertyName == 'GUID' || propertyName == 'ID' || propertyName == 'Id')   
              {
                 continue;
              }                  
              if(propertyName == '__metadata') {
                   var targetItemType = GetItemTypeForListName(targetListName);
                   copyItem['__metadata'] = { 'type': targetItemType };
              }
              else {
                  copyItem[propertyName] = sourceItem[propertyName]; 
              }    
          }
        }

        createListItem(webUrl,targetListName,copyItem,function(targetItem){
            complete(sourceItem,targetItem);
        },failure);
    },
    failure);   
}


function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    var itemType = "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem";
    var encItemType = itemType.replace(' ','_x0020_');
    return encItemType;
}
```

Example: copy task item

```
var sourceListName = 'Tasks';
var sourceListItemId = 7;
var targetListName = 'Archive Tasks';
copyListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,sourceListName,targetListName,sourceListItemId,printInfo,logError);

function printInfo(sourceItem,targetItem)
{
    console.log(String.format('List Item has been copied from {0} to {1}',sourceListName,targetListName));  
}

function logError(sender,args)
{ 
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

**Update**

The following example demonstrates how to specify explicitly what fields to copy:

```
function copyListItem(webUrl,sourceListName,targetListName,listItemId,complete,failure)
{
    getListItem(webUrl,sourceListName,listItemId,
    function(sourceItem){
        //prepare item
        var copyItem = {};
        var targetItemType = GetItemTypeForListName(targetListName);
        copyItem['__metadata'] = { 'type': targetItemType };  //mandatory, do not remove metadata attribute!

        //specify explicitly what fields to copy here..
        //...
        copyItem['Title'] = sourceItem['Title']; //e.g. copy title

        createListItem(webUrl,targetListName,copyItem,function(targetItem){
            complete(sourceItem,targetItem);
        },failure);
    },
    failure);   
}
```

> P.S. Use this `copyListItem` method instead of original one

Comment: I guess your code will copy all the column values of item '7' from 'Task' list to 'Archive Tasks' list,  but I want only few column values from 'Task' list to be copied to 'Archive Tasks' list. Both lists have different column names.

Comment: That's right, source and target lists must have the same schema. See the updated answer for a case how to copy specific fields

Comment: In that case lists do not require to have the same schema..

Comment: Your code worked like a charm, you are a rockstar :) Thanks a lot @Vadim :)

Comment: Karthik, glad it helped you! :)

Comment: I'm using this solution and it is working quite well.  However, I am trying to use your updated function and am not sure how to copy the Assigned To field over explicitly.  I am using `['AssignedTo']`, do I need to expand it in order to set it in the new item?

Comment: I read that REST is disabled on lists that exceed the listview threshold (5000 items by default). Is that true and if so, will this code fail on such a list?

Comment: How about a wildcard in a column to get certain rows of items to copy over?