# SharePoint 2013 App Office 365 copy list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, office-365

I try to build an SharePoint hosted app, have started with a custom menu action. When I choose it I want to copy the selected item and automatically change some metadata for it.

Problem is I can't get the data from the selected item.

I have tested this example but don't get it to work: [Copy List items using REST/JSON](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114755/copy-list-items-using-rest-json/)

```
function copyListItem(webUrl, sourceListName, targetListName, listItemId) {
    getListItem(webUrl, sourceListName, listItemId,
    function (sourceItem) {
        //prepare item
        var copyItem = {};
        var targetItemType = GetItemTypeForListName(targetListName);
        copyItem['__metadata'] = { 'type': targetItemType };  //mandatory, do not remove metadata attribute!

        //specify explicitly what fields to copy here..
        //...
        copyItem['Title'] = sourceItem['Title']; //e.g. copy title

        createListItem(webUrl, targetListName, copyItem, function (targetItem) {
            complete(sourceItem, targetItem);
        }, failure);
    },
    failure);
    }
    function getListItem(webUrl, listName, listItemId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying with or without complete and failure but then I got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: complete/failure is not defined  ??

and when I use complete and failure in calls I get :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev1.sp2013.local/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('skistardoks')/items(33). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://app-33cc412e378e5f.app.dev1.sp2013.local' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

--

using this call is ok?

```
$.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', getListItem(hostweburl, "skistardoks", "33", "complete", "failure"));
```

new code:

```
function getListItem(webUrl, listName, listItemId, complete, failure) {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")?@target='" + encodeURIComponent(webUrl) + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose' }, // consider using the other odata options that have a lower payload
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
```

error in

> Uncaught Error: Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url.
>   SP.RequestExecutor.js:2

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify data on the host site you need to use the [Cross-Domain Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927(v=office.15).aspx). For SharePoint-Hosted apps, this is the `Sp.RequestExecutor.js` library.  To get your code to work, simply replace the `$.ajax()` with the cross-domain equivalent:

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")?@target='" + encodeURIComponent(webUrl) + "'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { 'Accept' : 'application/json; odata=verbose' }, // consider using the other odata options that have a lower payload
    success: function(data) {
        complete(data.d);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        failure(data);
    }
});
```

Note that the executor uses method in place of type, and body in place of data.

In order to access the library, either utilize `$.getScript()`, or add the following script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
```

[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Get-items-7c27024f/sourcecode?fileId=101390&pathId=1361160678) is a working example from Microsoft.

Comment: thank you, changed it but then I get:

`code`Uncaught Error: Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url. SP.RequestExecutor.js:2
Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type SP.IWebRequestExecutorFactory has already been registered. The type may be defined multiple times or the script file that defines it may have already been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a partial update.`code`

Comment: Can you add your updated code and specify which line causes the error?

Comment: You are setting the `appweburl` variable, yes?